# Bullet and number indenting in list

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

I would like to make a custom indenting for lists:

1. Bullet or number is indented 1.2 cm from the left margin
2. Text (all lines) is indented 1.8 cm from the left margin

I am trying to use the `enumitem` package. It is easy to indent text with `leftmargin` option, but I can not succeed with bullet/number indenting. I have tried different values for `itemindent`, `labelindent`, `labelwidth` and `labelsep` but have not achieved the result I am looking for.

Here is MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep, topsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt, leftmargin=1.8cm}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is some text.

\begin{itemize}
    \item \( y_i = 1 \) if individual \( i \) is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed,
    \item \( y_i = 2 \) if individual \( i \) is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed,
    \item \( y_i = 3 \) if individual \( i \) is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive.
\end{itemize}
\noindent \rule{1.2cm}{1pt}$\bullet$ \par
\noindent \rule{1.8cm}{1pt} \par

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \( y_i = 1 \) if individual \( i \) is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed,
    \item \( y_i = 2 \) if individual \( i \) is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed,
    \item \( y_i = 3 \) if individual \( i \) is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive.
\end{enumerate}
\noindent \rule{1.2cm}{1pt}3 \par
\noindent \rule{1.8cm}{1pt} \par

\noindent Here is some text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used some boxes to calculate the widths:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\setbox1=\hbox{$\bullet$}
\setlist{noitemsep, topsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt, leftmargin=1.8cm, labelindent=1.2cm, labelwidth=\wd1, itemindent=*, labelsep=\dimexpr0.6cm-\wd1}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is some text.

\begin{itemize}
    \item \( y_i = 1 \) if individual \( i \) is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed,
    \item \( y_i = 2 \) if individual \( i \) is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed,
    \item \( y_i = 3 \) if individual \( i \) is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive.
\end{itemize}
\noindent \rule{1.2cm}{1pt}$\bullet$ \par
\noindent \rule{1.8cm}{1pt} \par

\setbox1=\hbox{1.}
\setlist{noitemsep, topsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt, leftmargin=1.8cm, labelindent=1.2cm, labelwidth=\wd1, itemindent=*, labelsep=\dimexpr0.6cm-\wd1}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \( y_i = 1 \) if individual \( i \) is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed is employed,
    \item \( y_i = 2 \) if individual \( i \) is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed is unemployed,
    \item \( y_i = 3 \) if individual \( i \) is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive is inactive.
\end{enumerate}
\noindent \rule{1.2cm}{1pt}3 \par
\noindent \rule{1.8cm}{1pt} \par

\noindent Here is some text.

\end{document}
```

The [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) presents a graphic of the composition of lengths regarding its horizontal spacing,. `leftmargin` is constructed from 4 others lengths; or you could specify all but one using `*` and it will be calculated. See section **3 More on horizontal spacing**, p 5. As is evident, it may be tricky to find out exactly which lengths go where...

[image]

Comment: I found out it is better to use `setbox9` and `wd9` accordingly. Usage of `setbox1` and `wd1` sometimes does not give the expected result. Probably they get over-written by some other command.